# Disposing Objects in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dbcontext

I am going to maintain one existing API implementation. When i look into the code i got that there are some issue with object dispose.

The following are my **Base Controller** which acts as parent controller for all.

```
[LoggingFilter]
[System.Web.Http.Authorize]
public abstract class BaseV1Controller : ApiController
{
    private ModelFactoryV1 _modelFactoryV1;
    private MyDBContext __db;
    private MyLoggingService _loggingService;
    private int _customerId;

    protected string __IPAddress;
    protected ILogger __logger;
    protected const int PAGE_SIZE_NORMAL = 20;
    protected const int PAGE_SIZE_MEDIA = 2;
    // GET: Base
    protected string __loggingResourceName = "Undefined - base controller";
    private void InitLogger()
    {
       Log.Logger.ForContext<BaseV1Controller>();
    }

    protected MyDBContext _db
    {
        get { return __db; }
        set { __db = value; }
    }

    public BaseV1Controller()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> values;
        __db = new MyDBContext();
        _loggingService = new MyLoggingService ();
        InitLogger();
    }

    public BaseV1Controller(MyDBContext db)
    {
        __db = db;
        _loggingService = new MyLoggingService ();
        InitLogger();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        _loggingService = null;
    }

  }
```

We are not overriding dispose method in the controller. In the controller we are calling Repository classes to do CRUD operations .

Sample implementation below;

**Controller:**

```
   [LoggingFilter]
    [ValidateModel]
    [Authorize]
    public class CustomersV1Controller : BaseV1Controller
    {
        IAsyncRepository<Customer> _repo = new CustomerAsyncRepository();
        public CustomersV1Controller() : base()
        {
            _repo = new CustomerAsyncRepository();
        }

        public CustomersV1Controller(IAsyncRepository<Customer> repo, MyDBContext db) : base(db)
        {
            __loggingResourceName = "Customer";
            _repo = repo;
        }

       //All Actions implemented here

    }
```

**Repository Interface and Class:**

```
    public interface IAsyncRepository<T>
    {

        Task<T> Add(T type);
        Task<T> Get(int Id);
        Task Update(T type);
    }

public class CustomerAsyncRepository : IAsyncRepository<Customer>
    {
        //saves the customer view models
        private MyDBContext _db { get; }

        public CustomerAsyncRepository(MyDBContext db)
        {
            this._db = db;
        }

        public CustomerAsyncRepository()
        {
            _db = new MyDBContext ();
        }

        public async Task<Customer> Add(Customer model)
        {
            //Add method implmementation
            return model;
        }

        public async Task<Customer> Get(int id)
        {
           //Implementation to return customer model
        }

        public async Task Update(Customer model)
        {
           //Implementation to update customer model
        }

    }
```

I have the following clarification based on this

1. I think we should include _db.Dispose() in the dispose method of BaseV1Controller. Currently I can't implement DI pattern.  Please suggest?
2. In Repository IDisposable not implemented. Is this correct?
3. Any other improvements?

Comment: Use a **D**ependency **I**njection (DI) framework. My personal preference is AutoFac. These frameworks handle the creation of dependencies as well as the release of resources used by the created instances (ie. calling dispose or custom cleanup methods). This includes injecting a `DbContext` instance and calling Dispose on it at the end of the request.

Comment: thanks and accepted. But as of now i don't want to change all area to include DI. Gradually i will do that. But now i am looking to stabilize without not much change and it is not allowable now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should dispose your DbContext in the base controller's Dipose method.  Otherwise, nothing knows that it needs disposing.  It may eventually be finalized sometime after the request is finished, but until that happens the underlying database connection will remain open and unavailable, which means you will exhaust your connection pool more quickly.

To ensure this happens, you probably don't want to have your _db property (which probably should be renamed to Db, or even better DataContext as property names in .Net don't normally start with an _) having a protected setter; a subclass could change the value of the property, and the original context which was there would be lost without being disposed.

Regarding the repository, the norm there is that if the class has a field which is an IDisposable, you should implement IDisposable in that class too.  What I'd probably do in this case is change your `IAsyncRepository<T>` to require implementing IDisposable as well.  Then your repository implementation should dispose the DbConext, and your controller would instead dispose the repository instance.  It would probably be best in that case as well to not have the controller keep any reference to the DbContext, and just expose the repo instance instead.

You can read more about how to correctly implement IDisposable here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks mate. ok i will dispose in BaseV1Controller. Yous second suggestion i can rename _db but if not any problem? I din't get your all points clearly here. Can you tell me that  i need to add IDisposable in Repository and override Dispose there also?

Comment: @Akhil Renaming the property is just a suggestion so that your code style matches what .Net developers will expect.  It was actually a bit confusing for me when I tried to read your code as you weren't following the conventions (and have double underscores for the field).

Comment: thanks. So overall suggestions should be to do 2 areas.  1) Need to dispose _db in the BaseV1Controller 2) Need to add IDisposable in repository interface and dispose Dbobject in each repository / generic repository also.